# SQL Nested Query MAX(date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a better way to structure my SQL?

I want to select the most recent event for each client.  The events are filtered by a where clause. If a client has no events that satisfy the where clause, I want to note that as well.

```
EVENT_DATE EVENT_STAFF     EVENT_TYPE  
1/1/2013   Myley_Cyrus     Music_Awards
3/1/1947   Albert_Einstein Noble_Prize
```

Currently, I am doing this:
 1. Select client ids.
 2. Select all events for those clients.
 2b. Filter those events.
 3. Select most recent filtered event or report 'X' (no events meet criteria).

The problem is that MAX(e_date) returns several rows, not just the most recent event (one row for each e_staff/e_type combo).

```
/* STEP #3: SELECT MOST RECENT FILTERED EVENT FOR EACH CLIENT */
SELECT          MAX(e_date), e_staff, e_type
FROM            client INNER JOIN events ON events.e_case_no = client.c_id
WHERE           events.id IN (
    /* STEP #2: SELECT FILTERED EVENTS FOR THOSE CLIENTS */
    SELECT events.id
    FROM events INNER JOIN client ON e_case_no = c_id
    WHERE client.c_id IN (
        /* STEP #1: SELECT CLIENTS */                                                               
       SELECT client.c_id
       ...
       /* STEP #1 END */
    )
    AND ... --FILTER THE EVENTS 
    /* STEP #2 END */
)
GROUP BY e_staff, e_type
/* STEP #3 END */
```

Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the `row_number()` windowing function

```
 select * 
 from
 (
      select *,
          row_number() over (partition by e_staff, e_type order by e_date desc) rn
      from yourfilteredrows
 ) v
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
Select e.id, staff, type, c.Name from Events e inner join
(Select max(e_date) Date, clientid from Events group by clientid) x
on x.Date = e.e_date and x.clientId = e.ClientId
inner join Clients c on c.id = x.ClientId
```